# CellEditor that uses JXDatePicker as editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, tablecelleditor

I need to make Date cells in my JTable editable, with a JXDatePicker. I suppose I need to implement TableCellEditor, but I don´t dare tackling it myself. Does anyone have a link or a quick piece of code that could help me?

Comment: See [the Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the JXDatePicker which is part of SwingX: it has a DatePickerCellEditor (in its table package) - because in this case it's not quite as easy to get the notifications correct :-)

Comment: yeah perfect :) I'll delete my answer :D

Comment: So if i understand correctly I just have to try something like this: someColumn.setCellEditor(new DatePickerCellEditor()). Or is this just naive? I´ ll try first thing in the morning :)